# Mounting /tmp with noexec option in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: server, partitioning, mount, 22.04

I have set up the Ubuntu VM (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) with the following options for /tmp: So that under /tmp, no execution is allowed.

```
cat /etc/fstab for /tmp:
    /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-tmp--lv      /tmp    ext4    rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
```

However, under /tmp, I can still execute the following shell script:

```
root@cdb30:/tmp# cat a.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "I am working"
root@cdb30:/tmp# ./a.sh
I am working

root@cdb30:~# findmnt -T /tmp
TARGET SOURCE                         FSTYPE OPTIONS
/tmp   /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-tmp--lv ext4   rw,relatime
root@cdb30:~#
```

Any help or pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `mount`'s option `noexec` is specifically for binary files and not shell script files AFAIK although I think in later versions it seems to affect those as well somehow ... However, why does your machine name change from `newUbuntuVM`  to `cdb30` and back ... Also, please, include the output of `findmnt -T /tmp` in your question.

Comment: Hi Raffa,

When I pasted the hostname, I made a mistake: It is cdb30:

root@cdb30:~# findmnt -T /tmp
TARGET SOURCE                         FSTYPE OPTIONS
/tmp   /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-tmp--lv ext4   rw,relatime
root@cdb30:~#

Comment: Hi :-) ... The `noexec` option isn't set for that mount as you can see ... How did you mount it? Is it added to `/etc/fstab` for example? Or by a custom systemd unit? Or do you mount it manually? Or by a script? ... etc ... Please, also add the output of `findmnt --fstab`.

Comment: One more thing ... Does `systemctl status tmp.mount` return anything? and if it returns the status of the unit, then please add the output of `systemctl cat tmp.mount --no-pager` ... Or do you see anything that relates to `/tmp` in the output of `systemctl list-units -t mount --all --no-pager`?